# VSTS Query Where clause

Tags: azure-devops

I have this following scenario -

I have a PBI whose Iteration is 'X'. It has a task under it whose Iteration is 'Y'.

Based upon the iteration value of the task, I need to get the parent PBI of the task.

Please let know how this can be done through a VSTS query. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to return the parent PBI based on the specific child Task ID, then you can try below query:

[image]

If you want to return all the parent PBIs based on the child tasks which under a specific iteration path, then you can try below query:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for the help. I have got the query what I want through your inputs and it works perfectly fine. But, there is an unrelated problem over here. I need to generate an chart from the results of the query. When I try to do so, it says "Charting is not supported for tree or direct link queries". What should I do over here?

Comment: @Shashidhar Unfortunately we can do nothing with chart, just as the message mentioned, charting is only supported for flat list query. It's by design.